# Does not work for Test Plans test suite and Test case link

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

i want to migrate test plan , test suite and test case from one project to another .

it is migrating all test case , test plan and suite but the link between them is not getting migrated .
if i go to test plan module and open my test plan it will not reflect my test suite and test cases.

is it possible?

i have attached the screen shot form source project , i want same in target project as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't migrate Test Plan or Test Suite items as there is no way to "wire" them back up to each other afterwards.

Using the [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) you will need to run the [WorkItemMigration](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Processors/WorkItemMigrationConfig.html) tool to migrate the Test Cases, and any other required items. Once you have all of the Test Cases migrated you can use the [TestPlansAndSuitesMigration](http://TestPlansAndSuitesMigration) to create a new plan and suite structure that as closely matches the original as possible.

Note: You will need to migrate any other Work Items, I can see Requirement bases Suites in your screenshot, that are referenced as well.

Comment: We have been facing the above issue. Our test cases migrated to new tenant but not the test plan or test suites. How do we use "TestPlansAndSuitesMigration" to create a new plan and suite structure?